# this.props is not a function in the componentDidUpdate()

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm facing a weird problem, there's probably a simple thing I didn't noticed but I'm not able to pass through this bug. Here's my case:

In the child, a counter is updated onClick. What I'm trying to do is fire a props function to togle the state of the parent.

In the child:

```
  componentDidUpdate(){
    if(this.state.counter === 3){
      return this.props.isFullBackgroundHomePage();
    }else{
      return;
    }
  }
```

In the parent:

```
  renderHomePage = () => {
    if(this.state.isHomePage
      && this.state.home_page !== null){
      return (
        <HomePage
          isFullBackgroundHomePage={this.isFullBackgroundHomePage}
          triggerSeeAllSection={this.triggerSeeAllSection}
          {...this.state}
        />
      )
    }else{
      return null;
    }
  }

  isFullBackgroundHomePage = () => {
    this.setState({
      isFullBackgroundHomePage: !this.state.isFullBackgroundHomePage
    })
  }
```

Now, this is what appears in the browser when the counter is at 3:

`TypeError: this.props.isFullBackgroundHomePage is not a function`

Link to the browser log: https://ibb.co/vcMW3wL

Comment: can you show more the parent component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
<HomePage
  isFullBackgroundHomePage={this.isFullBackgroundHomePage}
  triggerSeeAllSection={this.triggerSeeAllSection}
  {...this.state}
/>
```

you are overwriting prop `isFullBackgroundHomePage` using `{...this.state}` thus its not a function anymore rather a true/false boolean value at the consuming component. In your consuming component if you need both, you should rename state or prop value.

Very common issue unintentionally overwriting props using spread, gets the best of developer musing around what the heck is going on but to avoid such issues, consider using separate naming for function and state value to separate concerns.

Comment: Thank you -  I placed `{...this.state}` before and it did the job.

Comment: @cyruslk although that may resolve your issue, the problem remains if you have to use the value of the state within your child component thus you may need to rename state property to something else or just update prop name, use either option that works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I'm not sure however what you mean by _rename state property_? Could you give me a practical example?

Comment: Suggestion: change function name that changes state to `toggleFullBackgroundHomePage`. 
Your state has a property named `isFullBackgroundHomePage` and your prop has same name `isFullBackgroundHomePage`. Proper way would be to rename either one that way you are not confusing yourself or other developers.